# Activate next step on progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is my `ul` list for my progress bar

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active">
        <a aria-controls="select-room"><span class="mg-bs-tab-num">1</span><span class="mg-bs-bar"></span>Select Room</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="">
        <a aria-controls="personal-info"><span class="mg-bs-tab-num">2</span><span class="mg-bs-bar"></span>Personal Info</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation">
        <a aria-controls="payment"><span class="mg-bs-tab-num">3</span><span class="mg-bs-bar"></span>Payment</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation">
        <a aria-controls="thank-you"><span class="mg-bs-tab-num">4</span>Thank You</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

When someone selects a room by clicking a link, the we remove the class `active` from the first `li` and put it on the second, while adding class `step-done` on the first `li`, and the below jQuery is supposed to achieve that. However, when I look at the code via the inspect element, I see that it has added `class` instead of `class="active"`. When I instead add `step-done`, it works. What is it that can be changed to make this successful?

```
$(".nav-tabs li").removeClass("active");
$(".nav-tabs li").first().addClass("step-done"); 
$(".nav-tabs li").first().next().addClass('active');
```

Comment: Can you provide us a snippet with, at least, the Event Handler please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying all the suggestions from @Adeel and @Matthias Schmidt, I noticed that I still had the same problem. The script was not adding `class="active"` or `class='active'` instead, it was adding `class`, but when you changed to something else, it added. So I redefined the class `active` to `mynewactive` and it accepted to add `class="mynewactive"`

Answer (score 2):

`blue` color indicates the `.active` clas, `red` color is `.step-done` and the `green` color is just a normal color without any extra class.

Add click event only on `li.active` class such as `.nav-tabs li.active a`. `$(this).parent()` means the current parent tag which is `li` because the event handler takes place on anchor `a` and use `.next()` to find the next sibling of the current element. For more detail check [jQuery .next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/)

Please check below code snippet:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.nav-tabs li.active a', function() {
    $(this).parent().removeClass("active");
    $(this).parent().addClass("step-done"); 
    $(this).parent().next().addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.nav-tabs {
    list-style: none;
}

.nav-tabs li {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #5fba7d; // green color
    margin: 0 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
}

.nav-tabs li a {
    cursor: pointer;
}

li.active {
    background: #0095ff; // blue color
}

li.step-done {
    background: #dc3d4c; // red color
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active">
        <a aria-controls="select-room"><span class="mg-bs-tab-num">1</span><span class="mg-bs-bar"></span>Select Room</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="">
        <a aria-controls="personal-info"><span class="mg-bs-tab-num">2</span><span class="mg-bs-bar"></span>Personal Info</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation">
        <a aria-controls="payment"><span class="mg-bs-tab-num">3</span><span class="mg-bs-bar"></span>Payment</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation">
        <a aria-controls="thank-you"><span class="mg-bs-tab-num">4</span>Thank You</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my take on this, I hope it does what you want.
It removes the `active` class from the first element of that class, exchanges it with the `step-done` class and then adds the `active` class to the next step - it should work for all four steps.

```js
$('#advance').click(function(){
  var active = $(".nav-tabs .active:first");
  active.removeClass("active");
  active.addClass("step-done");
  active.next("li").addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.active{
  background:yellow;
}
.step-done{
  background:lime;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active">
        <a aria-controls="select-room"><span class="mg-bs-tab-num">1</span><span class="mg-bs-bar"></span>Select Room</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="">
        <a aria-controls="personal-info"><span class="mg-bs-tab-num">2</span><span class="mg-bs-bar"></span>Personal Info</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation">
        <a aria-controls="payment"><span class="mg-bs-tab-num">3</span><span class="mg-bs-bar"></span>Payment</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation">
        <a aria-controls="thank-you"><span class="mg-bs-tab-num">4</span>Thank You</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<button id="advance">Advance Step</button>
```